# Problema con consulta con variables en php usando ajax

Tags: php, ajax

tengo un problema al recargar una tabla con ajax, la tabla sealiza un fetch array para cargar los datos pero al momento de recargar usando ajax las variables de la consulta fallan por algun motivo cosa que me parece extraño ya que la consulta se realiza al inicio del html y solo el fetch array se realiza dentro de la tabla (intente quitandolas y funciona correctamente), mi pregunta es, ¿Como hago que al realizar la recarga a traves de ajax la consulta siga funcionando?

mi consulta

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from bienes,tipo,departamentos where $cons='$llave' and tipo.id_tb=bienes.id_tb and departamentos.id_dep=bienes.id_dep $con");
```

tbody de la tabla

```
           <tbody>
            <?php
                $cont = 1; 
               while($arreglo = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
                       $longitud = strlen($arreglo["nom_tb"]);
                       $letra = substr($arreglo["nom_tb"],$longitud-2);
                       $nueva = "";
                       if($letra!="e"){
                            $nueva = $nueva.substr($arreglo["nom_tb"],0,$longitud-1);
                       }else{
                            $nueva = $nueva.substr($arreglo["nom_tb"],0,$longitud-2);
                       }
                   ?>
                   <tr>
                       <td><?php echo $arreglo["cod_bie"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $nueva; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $arreglo["nom_dep"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $arreglo["mod_bie"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $arreglo["mar_bie"]; ?></td>
                       <td><?php if($arreglo["est_bie"]=="F"){echo "Activo";}else{echo "Dañado";} ?></td>
                       <td>
                            <?php
                               $prestado = mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from prestamos where id_bie='".$arreglo["id_bie"]."'");
                                if($prestado->num_rows>0){
                                    echo "Sí";
                                }else{
                                    echo "No";
                                }
                            ?>
                       </td>
                         <?php
                            if($miarreglo["per_usu"]=="A"){
                        ?>
                           <td>M</td>
                           <td>E</td>
                        <?php
                            }else{
                        ?>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-simple" title="Solo administradores pueden modificar datos"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></button></td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-simple" title="Solo administradores pueden eliminar datos"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
                        <?php   
                            }
                        ?>
                   </tr>
                   <?php
                   $cont++;
               }
            ?>
        </tbody>
```

Recarga en el success de ajax

```
 $("#tabla").load(location.href+" #tabla");
```

Comment: Porqué concatenas " #tabla" a la ruta? Además tiene un espacio... no el espacio nada más empezar el string: " #tabla"

Comment: No se entiende nada tu pregunta, [editala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/542233/edit) y pon el código completo de cada apartado, se mas especifico con lo que quieres lograr para poder ayudarte.